# Glide : Corner top Left and Right

Tags: kotlin, android-glide

I am facing with a specific problem with Glide.

I am trying to put top left / right corner but I dont know how to do this.

[image: Something like this]

I have this following code but it for all corner :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
@JvmStatic
fun setImageUrl(imageView: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {

    var requestOptions = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(16))
    Glide.with(imageView.context).load(imageUrl).apply(requestOptions).into(imageView)
}
```

}

Do you have any solution?

NB : I found this following website https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/rounded-corners-with-glide/

But I would like to know if they have another way.

Answer (score 0):

Not using glide But, This link might be helpful -> Android UI: creating imageview with rounded top corners in android - http://android--kotlin.blogspot.com/2019/02/android-ui-creating-imageview-with-rounded-top-corners.html

Its using the `drawable` corner frame in `src` and setting image in the background of the `ImageView` to create rounded top corners. `frame drawable` here has rectangle shape with radius and negative margin. So image is overridden by frame drawable from top corners.